# How to get first entry from the record in Laravel relation?

Tags: php, laravel

I got this query, it fetch results from my database, based on relationships.
The query works fine, but it grabs the first entry from the database/table and not the first value of the array.

How can I fix that?

```
            $motor = Motor::query()
                ->where([
                    ['effect_id', '=', $request->effect_id],
                    ['poles', '=', $request->poles],
                    ['voltage_id', '=', $request->voltage_id],
                    ['active', '=', 1],
                ])
                ->whereHas('MotorSize', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->whereIn('mounting', ['B5', 'B14', 'B34', 'B35']);
                })
                ->firstOrFail();
```

I have tried different things, such as:

Adding the orderBy to the Motor model and created a "priority" field in my database, giving each a number between 1 and 100:
(i actually thought this would work, but it still grabs the first entry from the table)

```
    public function MotorSize()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MotorSize')->orderBy('priority', 'ASC');
    }
```

I also tried something like this, but it's a mess and never got it to work:

```
$query->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('mounting', 'like', 'B5');
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('mounting', 'like', 'B14');   
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('mounting', 'like', 'B34');   
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('mounting', 'like', 'B35');    
});
```

Any suggestions will be welcome :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by wanting the 'first value of the array'? Can you not just do `->first()-><column-name>`?

Comment: By first i want to find the first motor where motor->motorsize->mounting is 'B5'. If no result, then grab 'B14', then 'B34' and last check for 'B35'. The problem is, it grab the first entry added to the database/table and not the value I tell it to order by.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work (getting an error): $query->whereIn('mounting', ['B14', 'B5','B34', 'B35'])->first()->orderBy('priority');

Comment: What's the error? I don't think it makes sense to apply an orderBy on a single result.

Comment: No errors received. I just receive the wrong result. I receive the first entry into the table and not the one with the lowest "priority" value (numeric). I got a column named "priority" in my table (motor->motorsize->mounting) and I need the result matching my where query, with the lowest priority value. This is where I fail. No errors received, which makes it even harder for me :/

Comment: Just to clarify. My motor_sizes table got some columns, two of them is named "mounting" and "priority". I need to grab the result with the lowest "priority value" or the "mounting" result that match the first placement (left to right) in the array (['B14', 'B5','B34', 'B35']). I guess ordering on "priority" was the easy way to handle this task - but cant get it to work. It keep grabbing the first table entry (the one with the lowest ID, autoincrement)